# The Security to the Party [Part 17!]

Tags: password

You arrive at the party and the host personally comes out to greet you. He invites you in to the party and takes you to his office.

What madness is this!?!?

He gives you a numbered list of ingredients for his famous meatball recepie, and tells you that some of the ingredients are red herrings (but none of them are red herring). He has encoded the numbers of the correct ingredients; you have to figure out how to decode them into the proper numbers. He gives you some examples: "6" decoded is "20", "2" decoded is "4", and "3" decoded is "8".

Your friend has given up. He says good bye and leaves. The host tells you that the correct ingredients are those with numbers decoded from "1", "7", "10", and "9". What ingredient numbers are correct?

**By the way, if you get this wrong a trampling elephant is waiting!**

Comment: He's saying there's a numbered list of various ingredients; some of them are "correct" in some way, but others are not. The "correct" ones are the ones whose numbers are the "answers" to 1, 7, 10, and 9.

Comment: @Envision You should be a mod y'know.

Comment: @warspyking I just don't have anything better to do!

Comment: @Envision Exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One would think:

> $4x-4$

Which gives

> "0", "24", "36", "32"

**Edit**

But that's obvious! So let's take a different road. How about

> Jumping prime numbers. Start from $x$ jump $x$ primes (including $x$) and add one.

Resulting in

> 2, 30, 42, 38

Comment: None of these are correct. By now you should know party-security questions are never obvious.

Comment: Wait! Where is that elephant-umbrella I had?

Comment: Then again, I do need some additional clue besides not being obvious, since it does fit...

Answer (score 2):

The sequence is

> powers of 2 in hexadecimal,
>  2^6 = 32 = 0x20 
>  2^2 = 4 = 0x04
>  2^3 = 8 = 0x08

So

> 2^1 = 2 = 0x2
>  2^7 = 129 = 0x80 
>  2^10 = 1024 = 0x400
>  2^9 = 512 = 0x200

Therewithal

> 2,80,400,200

Comment: $2^6 = 64$ is what they've taught me...

Comment: @JNF Base 32 then ;)

Comment: Nope #1 was correct though.